# No transactions recorded from server-side enhanced e-commerce events based on stripe handler

Tags: node.js, google-analytics, enhanced-ecommerce

I am trying to implement transactions notifications to GA property with Enhanced E-Commerce enabled from a stripe events handler written in nodejs.
My hits look like so:

```
v=1&tid=UA-12345678-1&uid=193p6r3o6g1i203d325g181r645bfu1m6ph6&dl=https%3A%2F%2Fdev.example.com%2Fvirtual-pages%2Fstripe%2Fpayment-succeed&dh=dev.example.com&dp=%2Fvirtual-pages%2Fstripe%2Fpayment-succeed&dt=Stripe%20-%20Payment%20Succeed&ua=events-server%2F1.0.0%20(Linux%3B%20Backend%3B%20Service%2Fstorage-api%3B%20Service-version%2Ftests)&t=pageview&qt=610
v=1&tid=UA-12345678-1&uid=193p6r3o6g1i203d325g181r645bfu1m6ph6&dl=https%3A%2F%2Fdev.example.com%2Fvirtual-pages%2Fstripe%2Fpayment-succeed&dh=dev.example.com&dp=%2Fvirtual-pages%2Fstripe%2Fpayment-succeed&dt=Stripe%20-%20Payment%20Succeed&ua=events-server%2F1.0.0%20(Linux%3B%20Backend%3B%20Service%2Fstorage-api%3B%20Service-version%2Ftests)&t=transaction&ti=transaction-1IdHQpKlqMBPMjkvcHFWTU9t&tr=359.4&qt=610
v=1&tid=UA-12345678-1&uid=193p6r3o6g1i203d325g181r645bfu1m6ph6&dl=https%3A%2F%2Fdev.example.com%2Fvirtual-pages%2Fstripe%2Fpayment-succeed&dh=dev.example.com&dp=%2Fvirtual-pages%2Fstripe%2Fpayment-succeed&dt=Stripe%20-%20Payment%20Succeed&ua=events-server%2F1.0.0%20(Linux%3B%20Backend%3B%20Service%2Fstorage-api%3B%20Service-version%2Ftests)&t=item&ti=transaction-1IdHQpKlqMBPMjkvcHFWTU9t&ic=lifetime-access&in=example%20Perpertual%20License&ip=599&iq=1&iv=permanent-license&qt=610
v=1&tid=UA-12345678-1&uid=193p6r3o6g1i203d325g181r645bfu1m6ph6&dl=https%3A%2F%2Fdev.example.com%2Fvirtual-pages%2Fstripe%2Fpayment-succeed&dh=dev.example.com&dp=%2Fvirtual-pages%2Fstripe%2Fpayment-succeed&dt=Stripe%20-%20Payment%20Succeed&ua=events-server%2F1.0.0%20(Linux%3B%20Backend%3B%20Service%2Fstorage-api%3B%20Service-version%2Ftests)&ec=E-Commerce&ea=Purchase&el=lifetime-access%2Fpermanent-license&ev=360&t=event&qt=611&ti=transaction-1IdHQpKlqMBPMjkvcHFWTU9t&tr=359.4&tcc=40DISCO&pa=purchase&pr1id=lifetime-access&pr1nm=example%20Perpertual%20License&pr1br=example&pr1va=permanent-license&pr1pr=599&pr1qt=1
```

I replaced some values for lexically similar for security purposes of course.
I tried all these variants:

1. no pageview, transaction and item hits
2. no pageview, event with products list, transaction details, and pa=purchase
3. pageview, transaction and item hits
4. pageview, transaction and item hits,
5. pageview, transaction and item hits, and transaction details and pa=purchase

I am in sort of despair about this, because I feel that something simple is overlooked, since when I use enhanced e-commerce events, the events themselves arrive at Realtime tab but they does not contain/show the e-commerce properties of course.
Basic and enhanced e-commerce features are enabled on view settings.
No transactions shown in the reports at all. Even from my tests I run 2-3 days ago in various combinations of hits.
I checked my hits with the debug endpoint (`/debug/collect`) and it claims my hits are valid and no warnings shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking at the data in a normal view (not a User-ID view) you will not see them because the request contains only the `uid` as identifier, while you also need the `cid` (clientId).

Comment: I omited the `cid` because from the docs I seen uid is enough to bind transaction event sent from server-to-server Stripe event handler to the other events with same uid. Do you have some hints on what can be used as cid in server-to-server context where browser not involved?

Comment: A random value, i.e 12345.12345 or 555 or abc123... you can use uid value as cid as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Other thing I may need to investigate is should I mark these purchase events as non-interactive since these payments can be made as part of subscription lifecycle or o should not set that ni parameter to 1 in this case...

Comment: You're welcome. It depends on how you want to read the data, in case of need open a new question with more detailed scenario, pls